# Error en instancias Pythom

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente problema:

```
 def agregar_asistente(self, asistente):

    if self.cupo > 0:            
        self.asistentes.append(asistente)                
        self.cupo -= 1            
    if self.cupo == 0:
        return None
```

Tengo una clase llamada Evento, que agrega un objeto Asistente a una lista de asistentes que esta clase posee. El problema es que los eventos tienen "cupos", una cantidad limitada de asistentes pueden acceder a ellos.
Cuando ejecuto la función para asignar asistentes a mis eventos, por ejemplo, 4 asistentes entran en un evento de 2 cupos (donde deberían haber únicamente dos asistentes).
Ese fragmento de código claramente explicita que si los cupos llegan a 0, no debería agregar nada, y luego de haber puesto prints ahí, de hecho corroboré que hace lo que le digo, sin embargo, los asistentes se asignan de todas formas, tengo entendido que es un error de instanciamiento, alguna sugrenecia?
Gracias.

PD:

Ejemplo: Tengo este Evento:

```
Evento_exclusivo("Capitán América",(10,13),2)
```

Siendo el parámetro 2 la cantidad de cupos disponibles.

Pero al agregar asistentes con el método de arriba, arroja:

```
{'Capitán América': ['Luciano', 'Julian', 'Lucas', 'Martin']}
```

Siendo los nombres la lista completa de los nombres de los asistentes, cuando sólo deberían estar Luciano y Julián.

Comment: Que hace la funcion evento_exclusivo? porque no lo estas mostrando. La funcion que mostras agrega asistente a asistentes, pero solo verifica si llegas a cero en el cupo, pero me parece que tu problema esta en otro lado

Answer (score 0):

Probe el código y funciona ok:

```
class Evento:
    def __init__(self):
        self.asistentes = []
        self.cupo = 2

    def agregar_asistente(self, asistente):
        print(self.cupo)
        if self.cupo > 0:
            self.asistentes.append(asistente)
            self.cupo -= 1
        if self.cupo == 0:
            return None


e =Evento()
e.agregar_asistente("uno")
e.agregar_asistente("dos")
e.agregar_asistente("tres")
e.agregar_asistente("cuatro")
print(e.asistentes)
```

produce

```
2
1
0
0
['uno', 'dos']
```

Nota:

```
if self.cupo == 0:
    return None
```

es innecesario.